# Row Space of Random Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, st.statistics, random-matrices

Say we have a Gaussian distribution in $\mathbb{R}^p$, $x \sim N(0, \Sigma)$, and a set of $n < p$ samples from this distribution, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$. The projector onto the row-space of $X$ is given by $P  =  X^T (X X^T)^+ X$. The distribution of $(X^T X)^+$ was found by [Diaz-Garcia et al](https://cimat.repositorioinstitucional.mx/jspui/bitstream/1008/696/1/I-03-05.pdf). Is there an explicit form for the distribution of $P$?